# Laravel 5.6 route updating form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

```
This is the mean problem
I have controllers structures like this
```

[image: File Structures]

```
And i am using this syntax to make routes which is worked good for me
```

[image: web/routes]

```
Updating form is
```

> {{ Form::open(array('method'=>'POST','route' => ['categories.update', $category->id])) }}

```
i got this error
```

[image: Error]

```
Any Solution ??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `put` method:

```
{{ Form::open(array('method'=>'PUT','route' => ['categories.update', $category->id])) }}
```

Because [`Route::resource()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers) creates `PUT` route for `update` method.

You can see all registered routes with their HTTP verbs and route names with this command:

```
php artisan route:list
```